# Celery, find the task caller from the task?

Tags: python, celery

Is it possible to lookup what code called (delay(), apply_async(), apply(), etc.) a task from within the task's code?  Strings would be fine.  Ideally, I would like to get the caller's stack trace.

Comment: Did you mean see the stack trace of the caller from the worker?

Comment: @pbhowmick Yes, from the task code as run by the worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no and that is by design.

Long answer is yes, you can always send in unneeded information to the worker whose sole purpose is to identify the caller and the caller's state.